# FOSUserBundle: How to best integrate login and register form in one template?

Tags: templates, symfony, authentication, twig, fosuserbundle

I am using the FOSUserBundle in my Symfony application which is really great. They have the login and register forms in a separate template. I want both in one template to display them next to each other.

Therefore I created `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/Security/login.html.twig` and `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/Registration/register.html.twig` to override both templates. In `login.html.twig` I call the register controller to render its template.

app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/Security/login.html.twig:

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error|trans }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" placeholder="{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}" required="required" />

        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}" required="required" />

        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
        <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</label>

        <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" />
    </form>

    {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register')) }}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/Registration/register.html.twig:

```
{% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}
```

But then I get the following error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /private/var/www/symfony/My_UserBundle/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Array.php line 31
```

I don't know why I get this error message. If I look into the `Security:login` and `Registration:register` controller, the templates get rendered in different ways:

```
$this->renderLogin(...
```

and

```
$this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html....
```

So basically I have two questions:

- What does the error message mean and how can I solve it?
- Maybe this approach is not ideal, is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use (as @Sidali Hallak said)

```
{% render url('fos_user_registration_register') %}
{% render url('fos_user_security_login') %}
```

But use your own versions of the `FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig` and `FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig` templates that don't extend `FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig`

Comment: sounds pretty good. But there is still a main problem left: The registration controller still routes to its own configured "/register" routes, which is not the route I want. How can I influence this? How can I tell him I want to route back to my page where login and register exist next to each other? I think it is not the solution to change the routing of the FOSUserBundle for this.

Comment: by the way: `{% render url('fos_user_security_login') %}` does not work. can you tell me why?

Comment: Have you imported all of the routes into your own routing file, the login route should be in there as should the base of the register folder? To keep from having to mess around with the controllers you could have the `{% render url('fos_user_security_login') %}` in the `FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig` although this would still mean that the login form will route to the original login route on a failed attempt. To do it properly I'm thinking you would need to customize the Registration and Security controllers.

Comment: This was an interesting solution to the problem.  What I am stuggling with is that it pulls the entire page including the styles so I get the header and the footer from my reg and login page.  Any thoughts on a way around this?  Ideally there would be a way to just render the forms for the page.

Comment: Are you using your own version of `FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig`? The original extends `FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig` which would be overwritten by your child bundles `ChildBundle::layout.html.twig`. Copying `FOSUserBundle:Security.login.html.twig` to your bundle and removing the `{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}` and taking the html out of the `{% block fos_user_content %}` should do the job.

Comment: To change the route of the form, you could override the form type as shown in the FOSUserBundle docs ( http://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) and change the action as shown [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form)

Comment: @Qoop I add ```{% render url('fos_user_security_login') %}```,but show me the login form and registration, Why? As I can do to show only the login. I think the fault lies sonataadmin

Answer (score 7):

To be compliant with newer Symfony versions, you should avoid using `{% render %}` tag and use `{{ render(controller('MyBundle:ControllerClass:action')) }}` instead:

```
    {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }}
    {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register')) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

use :

```
{% render url('fos_user_security_login') %}
{% render url('fos_user_Registration_register') %}
```

Comment: I add ```{% render url('fos_user_security_login') %}```,but show me the login form and registration, Why? As I can do to show only the login. I think the fault lies sonataadmin

Answer (score 0):

The max nesting level comes from **xdebug** and can be resolved setting ...

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```

... in your php.ini.

Comment: Thx, I thought it was a never ending loop what I got, because 100 nesting levels is really deep. This solved the error message. But I am waiting for more suggestions regarding a solution to solve my problem in a better way if there is one.

Comment: It seems that the Form component of Symfony2 makes heavy use of recursion, please see the official docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html (the relevant section is about 1/3 down the page)